# Uninstall hang `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic`

Tags: apt, kernel, raid

While trying to `sudo apt-get install -f`, the process hangs, with `dmraid` complaining about `/dev/sdd`:

```
Oct 17 11:43:37 aardvark kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Oct 17 11:43:37 aardvark kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
Oct 17 11:43:37 aardvark kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
Oct 17 11:43:37 aardvark kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d a8 00 00 01 00



$ pstree $PSTREE 17867
linux-image-ext,17867 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic.postrm remove
  └─run-parts,18392 --verbose --exit-on-error --arg=4.4.0-93-generic --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic /etc/kernel/postinst.d
      └─grub-mkconfig,29700 /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
          └─30_os-prober,30676 /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
              └─30_os-prober,30680 /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
                  ├─os-prober,30681 /usr/bin/os-prober
                  │   └─os-prober,30755 /usr/bin/os-prober
                  │       ├─dmraid,11036 -r -c
                  │       └─grep,11037 -q /dev/sdd
                  ├─paste,30683 -s -d  
                  └─tr,30682   ^
```

Since I don't use RAID, I'm confused.

How can I uninstall `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic`?

`/dev/sdd` was my `ext3` formatted StoryStation, which mounts as

```
/dev/sdd1 on /backvol type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,user=w3)
```

`sudo parted -l` tells me this about the StoryStation:

```
Model: Samsung STORY Station (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdk: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext3
```

It was powered up at the time of the hang.

I powered it off, `dmraid` failed, as did the `postrm` script. `sudo apt-get install -f` gave up. However, the next `sudo apt-get install -f` (with the StoryStation powered OFF) completed successfully.

Later, I sucessfully mounted and used the StoryStation.

This may turn into a bug report against `dmraid`w/StoryStation.